# Stackpanel animation issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation

**I try to implement animation of the set of different controls with different height with `Canvas` and `Stackpanel`.**

So I populate `Stackpanel` and apply all settings but anyway in the beginning animation is jumping for some time and only after this goes smoothly and when it ends it is again jumping 2-3 times and etc....

Any clue why is it? I use classic double animation and etc...

THANK YOU FOR ANY CLUE!

```
<Canvas  ClipToBounds="True" Name="canMain" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
   <StackPanel  Name="tbmarquee" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  ></StackPanel>
</Canvas> 

private void BottomToTopMarquee()
{
     tbmarquee.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;  
     DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
     doubleAnimation.From = -tbmarquee.ActualHeight;
     doubleAnimation.To = canMain.ActualHeight;
     doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
     doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_marqueeTimeInSeconds));
     tbmarquee.BeginAnimation(Canvas.BottomProperty, doubleAnimation);
 }
```

I have even tried like this

```
   Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
            delegate()
            {
                DispatcherOperation dispatcherOp =
                  this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(
                    delegate()
                    {

                        DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
                        doubleAnimation.From = -tbmarquee.ActualHeight;
                        doubleAnimation.To = canMain.ActualHeight;
                        doubleAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
                        doubleAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_marqueeTimeInSeconds));
                        tbmarquee.BeginAnimation(Canvas.BottomProperty, doubleAnimation);
                    }));
                dispatcherOp.Completed += new EventHandler(DispatcherOpCompleted);
            }));
            thread.Start();
```

I mean the animation doesn't start smoothly it is jumping.. but later goes quite well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I have animation performance issues, I can usually mitigate them by lowering the `FrameRate` and easing the demand on the rendering system. In my `Application` Startup method, I add the following:

```
MediaTimeline.DesiredFrameRateProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(System.Windows.Media.Animation.Timeline), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(10));
```

The WPF default is 60 (which is ridiculous, since even modern video never exceeds 30 FPS). I usually find a good performance balance around 10, but you can adjust this number until your animations look and perform as you want them to.

I hope this helps.

Comment: In which part of the application I have to include this code?

Comment: Like I said, I place it in the `Application` class, in the `Startup` event handler. It is a `Static` setting, so whenever you change it, know that it will affect ALL animations in your app. You can change it as often as you like...for example if you wanted to have a different setting for different `UserControls`, you would use this code in the `Loaded` event handler. Make Sense? I hope this helps.